# Spring security between two spring boot rest web services without login

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Hi I am very new to spring boot and spring security. I have two rest web services running on different servers communicating with each other. I want to make sure that api calls made between the two are secured using http basic auth. Most of the security demos/ examples I found online involved a login page for authentication. Is there a way to do this with the popup of authentication login page. Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Spring Boot uses http basic by default... SO unless you are reconfiguring things that should already be the default....

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. So I was finally able to implement spring security, but it is still allowing calls to go through even if the username and password are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, one application wants to interact with another one on the user's behalf.

You'll need the first application to send an authentication token to the second one.

If you're using Spring-Security , checkout [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/cas) solution. It is an SSO implementation that have an out of the box integration with Spring Security. You'll probably be interested in the proxy ticket work flow.
You can find additional details on the [Spring Security for CAS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html) page.

Another solution that I can think of is [OAth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).[Here you can find some more details](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/)

The decision depends on your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code below. It is still allows requests to go through even if the entered username and password are wrong

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
             auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```